# Como inicializar hibernate com reflection

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm

Olá, eu preciso inicializar uma lista utilizando Hibernate.initialize(lista) dentro de um DAO Generico.

#### Modelo Usuário

```html
@Entity
public class Usuario {

    @Expose
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<AreaAtuacao> areasAtuacao = new FastList<>();

    @Expose
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<AreaInteresse> areasInteresse = new FastList<>();

    @Expose
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private RegistroResponsavel registroResponsavel;
}
```

#### Modelo RegistroResponsavel

```html
@Entity
public class RegistroResponsavel {

    @Expose
    @OneToOne
    private Usuario usuarioCriacao;

    @Expose
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataCriacao;

    @Expose
    @OneToOne
    private Usuario usuarioAlteracao;

    @Expose
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataAlteracao;

}
```

Como inicializar a lista que está dentro de RegistroResponsável > Usuario > areasAtuacao & areasInteresse, utilizando reflection?